# How to fix problem with error while deploy page to gh-pages?

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

Today, I tried to run deploy of my page to `gh-pages`, but my computer crashed meanwhile.

When I restarted it - after run build, it stops on `gh-pages` build and shows error

```
error: bad signature 0x00000000
fatal: index file corrupt
```

I Tried to do the same with other pages and all works fine.
Please tell me how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try and clone the GitHub repository again, and see if deploy is working from this fresh copy.

If you had work in progress in the first local repository, you can try and copy it back to the new local clone.

The [OP Grzegorz Celek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15640202/grzegorz-celek) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68705052/how-to-fix-problem-with-error-while-deploy-page-to-gh-pages/68705092#comment121425974_68705092):

> I cloned it to new folder, download dependencies and then run deploy.
> Now all works fine.

Comment: It didnt work. After git push all is ok and all is update. When i check git status also all is ok. Only when I i try to deploy there is error after
 
gh-pages -d build

error: bad signature 0x00000000
fatal: index file corrupt

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! moja-aplikacja@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1

Comment: @GrzegorzCelek When you try to deploy from the new cloned repository? What is your OS and Git version?

Comment: Windows and git version 2.30.0.windows.1.
I did adding and deploying a lot of times but after computer crush it doesn't work only with that one actual project. 
I cloned repo and change files with old ones. Then try to deploy

Comment: @GrzegorzCelek Would the issue persists with git version 2.32.0.windows.2?

Comment: thanks for help. I cloned it to new folder, download dependencies and then run deploy. Now all works fine :)